# Downcasting the message received in Consume method

Tags: c#, masstransit

To limit the amount of Consumers (and busses), we try to group some processing in one Consumer()/Queue.

But I get into problems when casting the message in the Consumer to the right object.

Assume that I have one Consumer which should process two kind of request types.
The 2 sub request types derive from a base type, I send the message as a derived type, the Consumer method catches it as a base type, but it can't conclude the request type is one of the derived types.

I plan to create a Custom Consume() method for each derived type. And from the main (initial) Consume() method I want to call the specific custom Consume() method in one of the derived types, but I can't figure a way for doing this.

And related to serialization, because the serialization happens in the background, I can't manipulate this or I don't know how to do this.

I hope you understand my problem. Is there any way I can follow to accomplish this? Again, main reason for this is to limit the amount of queues, Consume methods.

Comment: "but it can't conclude the request type is one of the derived types" Why not?

Comment: I tried with 'is' 'as' 'isassignablefrom', but i cant cast it to the right type. The Consume method listens on the base type and I think it's impossible to downcast that. Actually your question, is what I'm asking too

Comment: But why can't you cast it? Do you get an exception? A null value? Anything?

Comment: Yes, InvalidCastException

Comment: That exception is thrown with explicit castings which should not be an issue with the "is/as" statements. Please post the relevant code where the exception happens.

Comment: This gives the InvalidCastException: (derivedType)BaseObj. I'll add code

Answer (score 1):

You should create separate consumers, one for each subclass, and consume the subclass directly. Otherwise you're just trying to duplicate that functionality that is already being handled by MassTransit.

Consider reviewing the documentation on creating message contracts, polymorphism, etc.

http://masstransit-project.com/

Comment: I posted an answer to my own question. Can you please give feedback on my answer? Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

`context.TryGetMessage` can be called, it does Json deserialization internally to the wanted type (if it's possible):

```
public void Consume(ConsumeContext<IGeneralInterface> context)
{
    ConsumeContext<SpecificImplementation> specificImplementation;

    if (context.TryGetMessage(out specificImplementation))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(specificImplementation.FieldIWant);
    }
}
```